# How to silence Xcode 4 warning "Semantic Issue: CFString literal contains NUL character"?

Tags: xcode4, warnings, suppress-warnings, cfstring

I am using something like:

```
illegalCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\x00\.."] retain];
```

Xcode 4 displays a warning for it

> (Semantic issue: CFString literal
>   contains NUL character)

Is there any way to fix that? I need that NUL character because I am stripping those characters defined in my "illegalCharacters" out of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
NSString *charSetStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C%C%C", 0, 10, 13];
illegalCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charSetStr] retain];
```

This way the string with NUL is not built until runtime and therefore no warnings from the compiler.